# Wordpress - Frontend User Profile Page with Associated Post Types

Tags: wordpress, profile

What I'm trying to do is have front-end profile pages for users of the site.

One method I was trying was creating a custom update profile page as seen here: (http://4rapiddev.com/php/create-custom-update-profile-page-for-wordpress-users/). I managed to set it up so that only registered users have access to that page.

Now for the difficult part (at least for me). I need to find a way to associate a specific custom post type (in this case, "badges") to individual users. That way, when a specific user goes to that page, those badges will be displayed.

Another way I was thinking of was somehow creating a new page every time a user is registered. That new page would have the same name as the user and be able to get the information that would normally come from viewing their profile in the WP-Admin. I managed to find a plugin that can associate custom post types to pages (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-types-relationships-cptr/)

I've tried looking around for both methods but came out empty-handed on both ends. Can anybody help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Anyone out there that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you are asking (in the first part of your message) how to associate a user to a custom post type, right? Since every post need to have an owner, I guess you can think these badges as custom posts and the users as the owner of these posts. You can list these custom posts automatically in the profile of every user. What else is missing, if you follow this logic?

Comment: by the way, you can also consider keeping badges that each user earn as a user meta.